# Adding a worksheet to a Powerpoint presentation from silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, excel, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm working on an silverlight client app that will create a powerpoint presentation that contains excel workbook sheets.

Going through the office api, the best way I can find to do this is to create the excel worksheet programmatically, save to a temp file and then use the AddOLEObject method on the shape object from the powerpoint api.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shapes.addoleobject.aspx

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the spreadsheet, copy the desired range to the clipboard, then with your PowerPoint object:

```
With oPPTPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex)
.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteOLEObject)
End With
```

Or if you need to move/size it:

```
With oPPTPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex)
Set oPPTShape = .Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)(1)
With oPPTShape
End With   ' shape
End With   ' presentation
```

That's it in a VBA nutshell.  Translation to .NETshell left as an exercise for the reader.